# Working with Pandas Groupby and multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas

I've searched everywhere and tried everything I could but can't quite get what I want from my data.

**Background:**

I have a set of data that has been derived from invoice data. I've massaged that data to get to the point where I have a pandas dataframe consisting of six columns.  These columns (and sample data is below):

- Project_ID - ID for the project
- Project_Type - type of matter of the work performed in a project.
- Create Date - Creation date of the project (when the project was initiated)
- Invoice Dates - Dates that invoices were generated for the
- Project Age - the age of each invoice (calculated from project initiation date)

Data sample can be found in [this CSV file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9kq3lr9cxy1kgsm/test.csv).

Each project can have multiple invoices, which is what is causing my issue.

What I want to do:

Aggregate by Project Type and get the min, max, mean and std of "Age" for each of project type.  I thought this would be a simple groupby using the Project_Type column but I can't get the min, max, mean, std functions to work as applied to that groupby.

I'm sure this is a simple issue but nothing I've found has solved it for me.

Any help or pointers appreciated.

Data sample:

```
Project_ID  Project_Type    Create_Date     Invoice_Dates   Age
25098       Computers       1/11/12 0:00    2/6/12 0:00     26 days 
25098       Computers       1/11/12 0:00    2/29/12 0:00    49 days 
25113       Telecom         1/12/12 0:00    4/30/12 0:00    109 days 
25113       Telecom         1/12/12 0:00    6/30/12 0:00    170 days
```

Comment: I realize it may be difficult to see the csv file link. Here it is: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9kq3lr9cxy1kgsm/test.csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eric, I didn't download your file, but I took a swing at it.  I would post the first few lines in your question so we don't have to download it.

Yes, groupby() would be a good way to go.  You can specify the agg functions in a list like this

```
df[['Project_Type','Project Age']].groupby('Project_Type').agg(['min',
                                                            'max',
                                                            'mean',
                                                            'std'])
```

Comment: Thanks...added a sample of the data

Comment: Bob thanks for this. This is similar to what I've tried but it still gives me an error.  Using this line throws a similar error of "ValueError: All objects passed were None"

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure the dtype of Age is an object or str.  Correct?

Comment: Great point. That fixed it. Thank you. I knew it was pretty simple but the '.agg()' is what I was missing.